# Rendering sub views, maintaining history and not re rendering the entire view. Is this possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I am migrating an existing react app over from using `director` to using `react-router`. While I'm loving it so far, maintaining history without re rendering an entire page was easy with director, and I'm not sure whether this is possible with `react-router`.

What I would like to do is have a view, let's call it `Slides` and two other nested view components let's call them `One` and `Two`.

In the router, these components would map to `/slides`, `slides/one` and `slides/two`.

`Slides` contains various layout components like `Header`, `Nav` and `Footer`. These are basically static.

Now, there is a transitional animation that will play when navigating between the slides. With my previous router, I was able to achieve this without having to render `Slides` and all its sub components again. After reading https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/266 and https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/3691 I figured that this may not be possible.

Is the accepted way to do this via `CSSTransitionsGroup` and just accept the re renders? It would be not so good for the UI if the render was slow and those static components blinked in and out or something.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define sub routes:

```
<Route path="slides" component={Slides}>
    <Route path="one" component={SlideOne}/>
    <Route path="two" component={SlideTwo}/>
    <Route path="three" component={SlideThree}/>
</Route>
```

Then on `Slides.jsx` you use `{this.props.children}` in your `render()` method to define where the child components will be inserted by the router.

`/slides/one` will render the component `Slides` and the component `SlideOne`, etc. When there's a change of route from `/slides/one` to `/slides/two` only the child component will be rendered. `Slides` will be not be updated.

To manage history you need to define a history prop on the router:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
...
</Router>
```

[These are the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) about the different history modules.